# How to retrieve recently updated contacts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

What is an efficient way to find recently updated Google contacts?

The obvious solution to retrieve all contacts with `ContactsApp.getContacts()` and iterate through all of them with `getLastUpdated()` doesn't seem particularly efficient and I am worried that such a code will exceed the time allowed if there are several thousand contacts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant with ContactsApp. You can use urlFetch and use the raw contacts v3 api. Use a query using updated-min, remember what your last updated-min was so you only get ghe ones updated since your last call. See the api and this: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters